# How to get the details of users stored in firebase using the id

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have been trying to retrieve the data of different users stored in my firebase project using the id provided to each user, but somehow when I pass the data to thunder client it shows invalid user or user doesn't exist.

This is the code I wrote.

```
module.exports.getUserDetails = async (req, res) => {
  const uid = req.query.id; // retrieve user ID from query parameters
  if (!uid || uid.length>128){
    res.status(400).json({error:"invalid user"})
  }
      try {
    const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(uid); // get user record from Firebase Auth
    console.log(userRecord)
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    const userDoc = await userRef.get(); // get user data from Firestore
    if (!userDoc.exists) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    const userData = userDoc.data();
    return res.status(200).json(userData); // return user details as JSON
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

I passed the url as localhost:4000/d?id=my_id

I called the function in my index.js file as app.get("/d",getUserDetails)

I get the error as {"error": "Server error"}in my thunderclient

```
errorInfo: {
  code: 'auth/user-not-found',
  message: 'There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.'
},
 codePrefix: 'auth'
}
```

this is the error that I get when I send the GET request from thunder client.

This is the details that I want to retrieve when a user id is entered, the program should return the user details the collection holds
[image]

The program should return

> ["food","travelling","technology","computer","cars"]

Comment: Can you show why you think the response your code generates is incorrect? I.e. can you log the UID, show us its output, and a screenshot of the document that you expect the code to read with that document ID.

Comment: I have added the informations , please take a look.

Comment: What is the value of `req.query.id` or `uid` when you log it in your Cloud Functions code?

Comment: it is the id that I pass onto my url , I am quite new to this so I don't know if this  is what you asked for.

Comment: You should console.log the value of `req.query.id` and/or `uid`, as it seems they're not what you expect them to be.

Comment: I solved it for you 